# Menus on Windows Forms in C# Desktop Applications

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding the menu in windows form which is looks like simple but I want menu with silver background just like windows 7 menu. Please tell me how it is possible?

Comment: I want a menu with silver background and I did it in past and now I don't know how to add it in my form

Comment: Use the MainMenu component instead of MenuStrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the appearance of `MenuStrip` except for the background color. So you have to overwrite the `MenuStrip` or draw your own menu by extending `MenuStrip`.